# Android Studio "Cannot find keymap windows copy"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, ide

I have installed android studio Bumblebee and after some time it's showing this error message in the **event log** when opening the IDE:

`Cannot find keymap Windows copy.xml, search for proper windows copy plugin`

I didn't change any settings related to the keymaps, yet this error is shown.

Answer (score 8):

Seems like the file named "Windows copy.xml" was corrupted. doing this solved my issue:

- Open this directory from Run menu by pressing **Win + R**: `%APPDATA%/Google/AndroidStudio2021.2/keymaps` (change 2021.2 to your version or just open Google folder and navigate to keymaps yourself)
- Open `Windows copy.xml` file and replace it's content with this:

  ```xml
  <keymap version="1" name="Windows copy" parent="$default">
     <action id="CheckinFiles">
       <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl alt r" />
     </action>
     <action id="UpdateRunningApplication" />
     <action id="android.deploy.ApplyChanges">
       <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl f10" />
     </action>
     <action id="android.deploy.CodeSwap">
       <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl alt f10" />
     </action>
  </keymap>
  ```
- Reopen your Android Studio

Comment: I had same problem, but with `Default copy` rather than `Windows copy`. Your solution worked for me, thank you. NB - I found my directory at `C:/Users/myUsername/AppData/Roaming/Google/AndroidStudio2021.2/keymaps`.

Comment: Glad it helped you solve the problem
Actually `%APPDATA%` points to `C:/Users/yourUsername/AppData/Roaming` in windows

Answer (score 0):

I got this error with PyCharm, so pasting in my configuration for it here.

Path: `%APPDATA%\JetBrains\PyCharm2023.3\keymaps`

```xml
<keymap version="1" name="Windows copy" parent="$default">
  <action id="CloseAllEditorsButActive">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl alt f4" />
  </action>
  <action id="Images.EditExternally" />
</keymap>
```